# Running google test in visual studio 2013 express

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, googletest, vs-extensibility

We've just switched to using google test for unit testing due to deficiencies in our previous framework.

In Visual Studio, I have a solution with multiple projects.  Each project contains unit tests using google test for a specific class (or collection of linked classes) within our application.  We only use VS for managing and running google tests and reference the test classes found elsewhere.

When I want to run all tests, I set startup projects to multiple, then press ctrl-f5.  This pops ups 1 console window per project with the standard google test output.  This is great!  I have to click a key to close each of the output windows, though.  It sure would be nice to integrate into "Test Explorer" within VS2013 express.

I've found this script runner:
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9dd47c21-97a6-4369-b326-c562678066f0.

It appears to be exactly what I want, but apparently express editions don't allow extensions?  (I'm new the land of visual studio.)  Anyway, we're using express instead of a different version because we're commercial.  My fallback solution is spending the money on a full version of VS.  However, I'd much rather find a free solution so I don't have to justify purchase, then deal with licensing visual studio for every new person that joins the group.

Has anyone figured out a solution to this?

Comment: Buying a full version of VS just for this is an overkill. Do you specifically want to achieve integration with "Test Explorer" in VS, or are you open to alternatives?

Comment: I'm open to alternatives.  Yes, it's overkill, but I've tested out the community edition and it's super slick and extremely easy to use.

Comment: Additionally, it seems if I get the extension working, I'll realize the benefits of native code coverage within VS, as well.

Comment: Did you end up buying the full version of VS?

Comment: I had an idea to do what you suggested in your answer.  However, we're not using gmock (we're using fakeit) and the time required to implement this was more than the cost of buying VS.  So, yes, we bought VS2015 professional.

Answer (score 1):

Our team also tried using "Google Test Runner" extension. The
integration with VS Test Explorer was great but we did not like
the fact that we could not see gmock warnings. This means that
some tests can pass with warnings and you will simply let that 
slip by and create problems in the future. The same problem 
exists when trying to use XML output generated by gmock.

Since viewing output in console is a poor option, we've decided to
parse the output of executable that runs the tests and display them
in a browser. To this end, we've modified the project so that it directs 
its output to a file ( "> test_output.txt" in Debugging -> Command
Arguments) and modified the main function to parse the output,
insert it into a html file template, save this html file and then open
it in default browser using:

```
ShellExecute(NULL, NULL, "test_output.html", "", "", SW_SHOW);
```

This also enabled us to make some customizations to the way results
are displayed using javascript.

You can use this approach in you case by creating a simple project which
will run last in the list of multiple startup projects, parse the output 
of other executables and display it in a browser. I know this solution has
its drawbacks, but it is (in my opinion) better than ignoring warnings.